# Jacoco code coverage - war file running in cargo

Tags: maven, integration-testing, jacoco, cargo

I asked this question before but never got an answer, I assume from the blog posts I have read this is possible but I cannot get it to work.

I want to run integration tests using selenium in my maven build, I am using the cargo plugin to deploy my war file to tomcat and the integration tests are with selenium. I am passing the jacoco arg line parameter to cargo on start up but cannot get the coverage results.

All my tests run but whenever I look at the generated jacoco report for integration tests there is always zero coverage.

I am posting my entire pom file as it is quite small and this might mean I get some help to get this working.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>uk.co</groupId>
<artifactId>netart</artifactId>
<name>MockitoTests</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>                      
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.0,2.3.99]</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.0,2.3.99]</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <!-- Exclude the Hamcrest core package that comes with JUNIT -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    com.github.klieber
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    phantomjs-maven-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[0.4,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute></execute>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Jacoco code coverage plugin for maven (see surefire plugin config) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                            runtime agent. -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        <includes>
                            <include>uk/co/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                    after unit tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-unit-tests</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <includes>
                            <include>uk/co/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                            runtime agent. -->
                        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>                                                
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after 
                    integration tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-int-tests</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Sure fire unit test plugin configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Failsafe Plugin for integration testing -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests 
                    property is true -->
                <!-- <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests> -->
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <phantomjs.binary>${phantomjs.binary}</phantomjs.binary>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT*</include>
                    </includes>                 
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>

        <!-- Installs PhantomJS so it doesn't have to be pre-installed -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- The version of phantom js -->
            <configuration>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Cargo Plugin - starts tomcat or jetty for integration tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <type>standalone</type>
                <!-- <skip>${skip.integration.tests}</skip> -->
                <!-- Install apache tomcat into the target directory -->
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.16.zip
                        </url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>                      
                </container>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>                           
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>                                  
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.jvmargs>${failsafeArgLine}</cargo.jvmargs>                           
                                <cargo.servlet.port>10001</cargo.servlet.port>                                          
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>                                                               
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.1</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>echo</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            <configuration>
            <echos>
              <echo>This is the Text which will be printed out.</echo>
              <echo>Displaying value of failsafeArgLineProperty</echo>
            <echo>[failsafeArgLine] ${failsafeArgLine}</echo>
            </echos>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.soebes.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-echo-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>echo</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The jacoco reports get created for both integration tests and unit tests, the unit test results are ok, the report shows them but no matter what I have tried I can never get the test coverage results for selenium driven integration tests.

Hopefully someone has done this and can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get a message like this?

```
[WARN] [09:31:44.247] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
```

In this case you may need to configure your maven-compiler-plugin to include debug information into your compiled classes using debug = true:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```